# Read integers separated by multiple spaces

Tags: c, formatting, text-files, scanf

I have a text file with a certain number of lines, and each line contains a certain number of integers. The integers are written inside one tab (a fixed width) of space, so the space between them varies with the length of the integer (in digits).

I want to process the file line by line but since the spacing between the integers varies I don't know how to read them nor how to also detect newline character in an elegant manner.

For a better picture imagine that the integers are aligned in columns that are each a tab wide.

Comment: `scanf()` / `fscanf()` / `sscanf()` should work here; it doesn't care how much whitespace there is between the numbers.

Comment: The `%d` conversion specifier will cause `fscanf` to skip over any leading whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.), and a blank space in a format string serves a similar purpose.  So you should be able to read two integers using `fscanf( input, "%d %d", &v1, &v2);` no matter how many spaces are in between the two in the input file.

Answer (score 3):

```
int nums[6][4]; // say it is a 6-line-4-integers-per-line text file

File *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");

int i;
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d", &nums[i][0], &nums[i][1], &nums[i][2], &nums[i][3]);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Because the spaces () are not matched with literal spaces, but instead whitespace (until a "real" character), this should work.

Comment: 1) Better to check the return value of `fscanf()`.  2) Using an example like `int nums[6][4];` would better convey the answer than `n by n`

Comment: @chux It's a simple answer. I'm not worried about checking `fscanf()`'s return value (guessing that it will be valid). But good point about the numbers